# Need help creating server out of Personal PC for small project

Tags: svn, login, remote, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Software engineering project in the near future in which a couple of students will be working on. I would like to host the database and maybe a source control server on my Local PC with hopes that the other classmates would be able to retrieve all of the information. I was looking into subversion for the version control software. I have sql server 2008 r2 right now. How would i make it to where I/ others can access the database on my computer without being on my network? Any information would be GREAT

Comment: Tell us more about your network: can you configure whatever networking gear might connect your network to the internet?

Comment: What do you mean by configure whatever networking gear might connect your network to the internet. Basically Me and another classmate are working on an assignment together. I/ we want to exercise version control and branching with something like subversion or mercurial. We also will need a central database. I was figuring i could host all of this on my local computer and set it up to where he (at his house, not on my network) could connect and get/ work on the same files

Comment: You can use github (git) or bitbucket (mercurial) for the source control. They're free to low cost, and will allow you each to keep a local repo, and merge your changes as needed. Otherwise, yeah, you can set it up on your pc, but you'll need to give the other student access to your pc via your network. For a central database, you can find free to low cost mysql hosting and use that, or if you really need SQL Server, have everybody run their own local instance of SQL Express that they can work against.

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

1. Set up your ISP router to do port forwarding for your database and
   version control ports to your PC.
2. Get a static IP address or use DynamicDNS for your home internet 
   connection, so you can tell your fellow students how to get to your 
   PC.
3. Secure the hell out of your personal PC because you have opened
   it up to the internet.

If you have any resources at all, I would strongly consider setting up this server separately from your personal PC - if possible use some sort of hosting service outside of your home network, as suggested by Joe Internet in the comments above.  You'll learn a lot about how these things are done in the real world, and will not be opening up a hole to your personal systems.